# How to setup site for no www

Tags: dns, iis7, no-www, configuration

The company I'm working at handles the hosting our self. We got `www.domain.com` up now and we want to make the `domain.com` to work as well. We use IIS7. I have seen some articles and found one with URL rewrite setting that can be added to IIS7. What's the best way to go? We don't want to cut any corners we want to do it properly.

This is the article that I mentioned above: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2009/11/27/iis-url-rewrite-rewriting-non-www-to-www.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This [topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180902/301-redirect-or-bind-more-domain-names-in-iis7-win2008) can help you.

Personally, I prefer to use additional binding.